# How to support kerberos SSO on app which is wkwebview based？

Tags: ios, enterprise

We are working on supporting kerberos SSO on out app which is wkwebview based. Is there anyone know how to implement it? I searched a lot of articles and docs - but did not find any useful.

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar requirement for our product. As far as I have worked on WKWebView, it does not support kerberos auth. We ended up using UIWebView.

I read in one of the Apple forums, says kerberos is outdated auth mechanism.

Today I got a news saying from April 2020 Apple wont accept new apps using UIWebView and from Dec 2020 they wont accept updates to apps using UIWebView.

Only option we are left with is to move out of kerberos auth.

Let me know if you found a way or any alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is supposed to be a business application deployed as a managed app through an MDM, you have a couple of options.

One option would be to use a product like [Hypergate](https://hypergate.com), which will allow your app to access kerberized resources transparently.

The second option would be to use the Apple's default [Kerberos SSO extension](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/extensiblesinglesignonkerberos), which can be configured through an MDM.

Both option will with apps using WKWebView, UIWebView, NSURLSession, NSRULConnection, etc.

Disclaimer: I work for Hypergate.